# zsh with iterm 2 does not recognize my alias

Tags: macos, alias, zsh, iterm

When I add an alias to `~/.zshrc` such as `alias dir='cd ~/Desktop/somedir'` and do `source ~/.zshrc`, it says "command not recognized 'cd " when trying to use the alias in iterm 2.

However if I create the alias inside of **iTerm 2** and not the `~/.zshrc` file, it does recognize it. Anyone knows why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: Found this while trying to figure out how to add aliases in general, and your question gave me the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the single-quotes in your `~/.zshrc` are not recognized as such and thus zsh assumes that two aliases are given: The definition of `dir='cd` and a query of `~/Desktop/somedir'` instead of `dir='cd ~/Desktop/somedir'`. (zsh allows for multiple alias definitons and queries in one command)

Most likely the single quotes you are using are not `'` from ASCII (ASCII code `0x27`) but some Unicode representation. Depending on your editor it is possible that they got replaced automatically when you edited your `~/.zshrc`. To be sure use an text editor that doesn't do any such 'auto-magic' (unless you tell it). I think of `nano`, `vim` and/or `emacs` are available on recent OS X versions.

Comment: This was 100% the problem. I was letting the file open is the default TextEdit. Once I opened it in Sublime and edited from there, everything was fine. Good thinking!